# Realizing Haar random unitary matrix on IBM Q

Tags: ibm-q-experience, haar-distribution

I am thinking about if it is possible to achieve Haar random single qubit unitary matrix on some real quantum computers like IBM Q. I am reading a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.04338. In this paper, they mention that they use Haar uniform single qubit rotation. But I don't know how this is achieved and how large the error should be.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with qiskit, you can use the `random_unitary` function right away:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate

haar_random_gate = UnitaryGate(random_unitary(2))
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.append(haar_random_gate, [0])
```

You can then execute this circuit normally.

---

If you want to do it by hand, which can be useful if you want to use another framework which doesn't have such a method, according to [this link](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_haar_measure.html), an Haar-random matrix is a matrix that can be written as:
$$U_H(\theta,\varphi,\omega)=\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\varphi+\omega}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)&-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{\varphi-\omega}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\varphi-\omega}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)&\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{\varphi+\omega}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\end{pmatrix}$$
with $\varphi$ and $\omega$ being uniformly sampled from $[0\,;\,2\pi]$ and $\theta$ being sampled from $[0\,;\pi]$ with density function $f(\theta)=\frac12\sin(\theta)$.

You thus simply have to create such a matrix with the correct distribution (you can for instance take the code from the Pennylane link above) to generate such a matrix.